# how to change individual value in koalas dataframe?

Tags: spark-koalas

I'm looking to update a single value in a koalas dataframe by passing its positional index.

I have tried using iat but keep running into errors. For example, if I tried:

```
df.iat[2,3]=5
```

I get an error saying 'iAtIndexer' does not support item assignment. This worked previously in pandas and am not sure if there is a different method in Koalas.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Mike, I think this is more of a mindset thing. Spark and Dask don't have indexes similar to Pandas because the index is a global ordering of data that becomes very expensive to maintain across several machines. Koalas will have some hack to add an index to a Spark DataFrame, but this operation may not be supported because it's very expensive to have bookkeeping for data location at this level. Instead, think of this operation as a filter and then modification of the value.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for the response. It makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
kdf.iloc[0,1]=999
kdf
```

out:

```
 id      A    B     C  D
0   1  999.0  2.0  99.0  0
1   2    3.0  4.0   NaN  1
2   3    NaN  NaN   NaN  5
3   4    NaN  3.0   1.0  4
```